# How do I run a command for each UDP packet with socat?

Tags: linux, networking, socat

I'm trying to print each arriving UDP packet. I'd like to use `xxd` to print the ascii contents as well as the raw data (as hex).

So far I've used 
`socat - udp4-listen:11255,reuseaddr,fork | xxd`

This sort of works, but `xxd` buffers the input until it can print a complete line of output.

I'd like `socat` to execute a new command for each arriving udp packet. I've tried

`socat  -u udp4-listen:11255,reuseaddr,fork system:"/usr/bin/xxd - /tmp/foo"`

It forks a new `xxd` for each packet (which is good) but keeps it running instead of closing the input after passing the packet.

Is there a way to make `socat` close the input of the forked process after passing the UDP packet?

Answer (score 4):

`socat -u udp4-recvfrom:11255,reuseaddr,fork exec:"/usr/bin/xxd - /tmp/foo"`

does it. The difference is using `udp4-recvfrom` instead of `udp4-listen`. The former seems to handle input per packet, while the latter concatenates packets into a stream.